# Spring Content GCS

Tags: spring

I'm trying out [Paul Warren's Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content) to serve some mp3 files. I've successfully used the simple sample for serving files from my filesystem. This works.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
public static class AppConfig {
    File filesystemRoot() {
        return new File("/home/some-dir");
    }

    @Bean
    public FileSystemResourceLoader fsResourceLoader() throws Exception {
      return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
@StoreRestResource(path="songs")
public interface SongsStore extends Store<String> {
//
}
```

Now I understand there's a way of serving files from a GCS bucket. But I've had **no success** :(. I've seen the [spring-content-examples](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples) and [spring-content docs](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) but I'm a bit lost.

From [this section](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/refs/release/1.2.6/gcs-index.html#_gcs_content_stores) in the docs I think I have to do something like this?

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGCPStorage
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Storage storage(CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider, 
            GcpProjectIdProvider projectIdProvider) throws IOException {

        return StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(credentialsProvider.getCredentials())
                .setProjectId(projectIdProvider.getProjectId()).build().getService();
    }
    @StoreRestResource(path="songs")
    public interface SongsStore extends GCPStorageContentStore<String, String> {
      //
    }
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work. So any help would be really appreciated! Even a nudge in the right direction, or a suggestion to do things differently.

Comment: Y the negative vote tho?